# Android app crashes after dismissing notifications from web

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, notifications, global-inbox

The SE Android app (v1.0.85 beta) crashes if I dismiss the inbox notification from web. It also fails the automatic notification dismissal on the Android.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Receive a notification (e.g. comment on your post, comment reply, chat ping, etc).
2. Dismiss the notification *from the web* (i.e. by opening and closing the inbox)
3. The app suddenly crashes (even when it's not active), showing a standard crash dialog to report/close.

Other notes:

- Dismissing the *Android notification* doesn't affect this issue; the app still crashes.
- **When the app crashes, the Android notification isn't dismissed** (either the cause/side-effect of this bug).

In case it's relevant, this is on Nexus 5 running Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow.

**LogCat**

```
04-04 08:56:30.776: I/GCM(2043): GCM message com.stackexchange.marvin 0:1459731391706656%553e5aedf9fd7ecd
04-04 08:56:31.094: E/AndroidRuntime(16021): Process: com.stackexchange.marvin, PID: 16021
04-04 08:56:31.094: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at com.stackexchange.marvin.core.inbox.GlobalInbox.setUnreadCount(GlobalInbox.java:35)
04-04 08:56:31.094: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at com.stackexchange.marvin.GCMIntentService.handleMessage(GCMIntentService.java:92)
04-04 08:56:31.094: E/AndroidRuntime(16021):    at com.stackexchange.marvin.GCMIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMIntentService.java:66)
04-04 08:56:45.872: I/ActivityManager(815): Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{c0bff52 u0 com.stackexchange.marvin/.GCMIntentService}
04-04 08:57:12.228: I/ActivityManager(815): Process com.stackexchange.marvin (pid 16021) has died
04-04 08:57:12.229: W/ActivityManager(815): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.stackexchange.marvin/.GCMIntentService in 1000ms
```

Comment: Can you confirm this has been fixed? Since there was never any 1.0.86 version, I'm not sure.

Comment: @ShadowWizard somehow, it's already fixed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.86.

When the unread count is cleared, the app gets the message via an intent service (not the main queue).  It then resets the inbox count and uses [otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) to pass the message to the running activity (if any).  I knew otto would only call subscribers from the main queue, but I didn't realize it did this by crashing when posting a message from a background queue.  Now the inbox will be updated in a handler on the main looper.  We were already doing this for new notifications.